# Codility: Passing cars in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm currently practicing programming problems and out of interest, I'm trying a few Codility exercises in Lua. I've been stuck on the `Passing Cars` problem for a while.

Problem:

```
A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. The consecutive elements of array A represent consecutive cars on a road.

Array A contains only 0s and/or 1s:

0 represents a car traveling east,
1 represents a car traveling west.
The goal is to count passing cars. We say that a pair of cars (P, Q), where 0 ≤ P < Q < N, is passing when P is traveling to the east and Q is traveling to the west.

For example, consider array A such that:

  A[0] = 0
  A[1] = 1
  A[2] = 0
  A[3] = 1
  A[4] = 1
We have five pairs of passing cars: (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4).

Write a function:

function solution(A)

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns the number of pairs of passing cars.

The function should return −1 if the number of pairs of passing cars exceeds 1,000,000,000.

For example, given:

  A[0] = 0
  A[1] = 1
  A[2] = 0
  A[3] = 1
  A[4] = 1
the function should return 5, as explained above.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1.
Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
Elements of input arrays can be modified.
```

My attempt in Lua keeps failing but I can't seem to find the issue.

```
local function solution(A)
    local zeroes = 0
    local pairs = 0
    for i = 1, #A do
        if A[i] == 0 then
           zeroes = zeroes + 1
        else
            pairs = pairs + zeroes
            if pairs > 1e9 then
                return -1
            end
        end
    end
    return pairs
end
```

In terms of time-space complexity constraints, I think it should pass so I can't seem to find the issue. What am I doing wrong? Any advice or tips to make my code more efficient would be appreciated.
FYI: I keep getting a result of 2 when the desired example result is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement says A is 0-based so if we ignore the first and start at 1, the output would be 2 instead of 5. 0-based tables should be avoided in Lua, they go against convention and will lead to a lot of off-by one errors: `for i=1,#A do` will not do what you want.

```
function solution1based(A)
    local zeroes = 0
    local pairs = 0
    for i = 1, #A do
        if A[i] == 0 then
           zeroes = zeroes + 1
        else
            pairs = pairs + zeroes
            if pairs > 1e9 then
               return -1
            end
        end
    end
    return pairs
end
print(solution1based{0, 1, 0, 1, 1}) -- prints 5 as you wanted

function solution0based(A)
    local zeroes = 0
    local pairs = 0
    for i = 0, #A do
        if A[i] == 0 then
           zeroes = zeroes + 1
        else
            pairs = pairs + zeroes
            if pairs > 1e9 then
               return -1
            end
        end
    end
    return pairs
end

print(solution0based{[0]=0, [1]=1, [2]=0, [3]=1, [4]=1}) -- prints 5
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I overlooked that. Changing the index from 1 to 0 did the trick.